# Grouping the tables with dropdown box

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am a beginner in google app script. So right now I am doing a project where users can sign in and can view their payment history. So for now it is just showing from 2020 until 2021. So I want your guys help on creating a dropdown box which states (eg : 2020 , 2021 ) so maybe if the user clicks 2020 then they can see the payment history of 2020 only. I really need your guys help in this thing. I have attached the link to my google app script and a image to explain myself better. Thank you guys.

https://script.google.com/d/1DdRKqUX__-ZITUgTZanQ_A7hUL1kcc0TZOeFmn58wYsX_o_7cqNExnYo/edit?usp=sharing - Link to my appscript

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwm1G.jpg)

[Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8L4l.jpg)

Comment: You can use a  [SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newDataValidation()) There are a lot of choice but usually user a list or a range your choice.

Comment: @MetaMan Sorry bro. I am a newbie to google appscript. Can you help me out with this thing. I really appreciate your help bro. Hopefully you will lend a hand for me

Comment: Share what you've tried and ask questions when you need help

Comment: Upon checking your code, once the user tried to login you will display all transaction made by that user in the table. My idea is to save the username in your html once it passed the login process. Then when you select a drop-down option, basically you can save the array response in your html then filter the array if the drop-down was selected. Or modify GetRecords(username) / create another one but the difference is you will add data to the resultArray if the month index has the year specified in the drop-down option.

Comment: If you still need further assistance please provide a sample sheet containing your sample data. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: @RonM bro your idea seems promising. I would really aprreciate if you help me to solve it bro.

Comment: @RonM https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bM8l6JefFsPrlJnTWf56wOhnuSjdIwg3hMbY1tN1Zp8/edit?usp=sharing. This is the link yo my google sheet bro

Comment: @RonM Bro I am trying to do the dropdown box as dependent box which means value for the dropdown box will be in the google sheet link I have provided. I provide one link to my appscript which contains the coding you have modified and another to my appscript which contains the coding for dependent box bro. Could you help me to combine it. Thanks in advance bro. https://script.google.com/d/1toEXTewITrSFNU_rDuSGkLfdH2_6ha-GTz5Q-McaNtlPIkoPaom4lrLo/edit?usp=sharing - Link 1 
https://script.google.com/d/1wShOduf0emll7LqGsgA_jSxJdfcjw_4x2Ar1eyQ-BeHGblL0oe8M2YYY/edit?usp=sharing - Link 2

Comment: @RonM Bro I have an error to the code you have updated bro. I paste the link here bro. Could you have a look on it. Thank you so much bro.
https://script.google.com/d/1toEXTewITrSFNU_rDuSGkLfdH2_6ha-GTz5Q-McaNtlPIkoPaom4lrLo/edit?usp=sharing - Link to appscript

Comment: What error did you encountered? when i copied your code it is working from my side. By the way i changed this line document.getElementById("firstLastName").innerHTML = "USER: " + username; . You can check my [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17yRie_s2oKkBGEJAZxVfV4TLw5TE-4S3tFm2NAZtjMA/edit?usp=sharing). Just update the sheet url in the script and deploy the app

Comment: @RonM  I seriously dont know why it was not working yesterday bro but its working absolutely fine now. Thank you so so much bro.  But I have one last question bro. Only you can help me because you only understood my problem bro. So sorry for annoying you bro one last help. In my coding bro, I have set the range in ,function `GetPaymentRecords(userProperties,filter)` from G:AD for `paidMonthValues` but I want to set it until last column bro. Would you help me on it. This would be the last help bro.

Comment: Use this syntax: `//Get last column of the sheet
  var lastColumn = displaySheet.getRange(1,displaySheet.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation().replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
  var rangeStr = "G:"+lastColumn;
  Logger.log(rangeStr);
  var addressValues = displaySheet.getRange("B:C").getValues();
  var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange(rangeStr).getValues();`

Comment: @RonM It is working fine bro. Thank you so much for being with me helping me with this project. Bro, I would like to ask to last help bro. Dont get annoyed bro. Sorry for disturbing you again and again. I have done some changes to the coding bro. After doing the changes when I add the coding you have written here, it is compiling bro but then the application is not working. The program is just keep on loading bro. Could you help me to sort it out? I paste a new link for it. Hope you could help me on this. Thank you so much bro

Comment: @RonM https://script.google.com/home/projects/1xV7FDVgp10XbGFtPJDUnhqm1GYybKZeKEI2L84Slp34rndOWgVJ1iScm/edit If you managed to find the problem, just edit there and save bro because it is one of my example version so I can copy from there. Thank you bro

Comment: fixed the error related to loading issue. You mistakenly replaced var `filterString = result.filter;` with `var filterString = ar.filter;`. However, even though the elements's innerHtml was updated successfully. I don't know why it was not displayed in the webpage. You can check the alert messages that i included to debug your code. Sorry I'm not that expert in html code.

Comment: @RonM Bro sorry for disturbing you. Would you mind helping me on something?

Comment: Hi @MATHAVANALKRISHNAN, I'm sorry to say but this thread goes beyond its original issue which might conflict with stackoverflow guidelines. If you still need further support in your project you can post new a new thread

Comment: @RonM Bro sorry for again and again coming to you. Really sorry bro for annoying bro. But now I need some help, here in this link right after I click the year and press submit button I says that records is not found bro. Could you help me to see what is the problem. So sorry bro https://script.google.com/home/projects/1DdRKqUX__-ZITUgTZanQ_A7hUL1kcc0TZOeFmn58wYsX_o_7cqNExnYo/edit -Link to appscript

Comment: I think the project is in view only. I can't edit the script

Comment: @RonM I have changed into editor mode bro. Can you help now bro

Comment: You modified this `alert(name);
          document.getElementById("currentUser").value = name; // CHANGE` currentUser element should keep the username which will be checked in `GetRecords()` but you replaced it with user first name and last name

Comment: i added some alert messages so that you can check it as well from your side

Comment: @RonM Thank you bro. I understood it bro. But if you have time right bro, can you help me with the problem in the post I have shared you here. This is my project bro. Your help in this one means alot to me bro. Hope you can help me. Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640822/adding-a-row-based-on-condition-using-google-app-sheet - Link to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Here is a sample code you can refer with:

**WebAppLogin.html (modifications)**

```
<script>
    function GetRecords() {
      var spin = "<span class=\"spinner-border spinner-border-sm\" role=\"status\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></span>";
      spin += " Loading...";
      document.getElementById("LoginButton").innerHTML = spin;

      var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output) {
        console.log(output);
        var username = output[1];
        var name = output[2];
        if(output[0] == 'TRUE') {
          document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("currentUser").value = username;
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayTable).GetRecords(username,"None");

        } else if(output[0] == 'FALSE') {
          document.getElementById("firstLastName").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("currentUser").value = "";
          document.getElementById("myFilter").innerHTML = "";
          document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML = "Failed to Login";
          document.getElementById("LoginButton").innerHTML = "Login";   
        }
      }).checkLogin(username, password);
    }
    
    function filter(){
      var filterStr = document.getElementById("filterYear").value;
      var user = document.getElementById("currentUser").value;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayTable).GetRecords(user,filterStr);
    }

    function displayTable(result) {
      var ar = result.data;
      var filterString = result.filter;
      var username = document.getElementById("currentUser").value;
      if(ar.length > 0) {
        var displayTable = '<table class=\"table\" id=\"mainTable\" >';

        displayTable += "<tr>";
        displayTable += "<th>Month</th>";
        displayTable += "<th>House Number</th>";
        displayTable += "<th>Street</th>";
        displayTable += "<th>Payment Status</th>";
        displayTable += "</tr>";

        ar.forEach(function(item, index) {
          displayTable += "<tr>";
          displayTable += "<td>"+item[0]+"</td>";
          displayTable += "<td>"+item[1]+"</td>";
          displayTable += "<td>"+item[2]+"</td>";
          displayTable += "<td>"+item[3]+"</td>";
          displayTable += "</tr>";
        });

        displayTable += "</table>";

      } else {
        var displayTable = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold\" >No Records Found</span>";
      }
      
      var filter = '';
      if(filterString.length > 0) {
        filter += '<label for="years" style="font-size: 20px">Years</label><br><select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="filterYear" name="years" required><option value="" selected>Choose...</option>';
        
        filterString.forEach(str => {
          filter += '<option value="'+str+'">'+str+'</option>';
        });


        filter += '</select><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="FilterButton" onclick="filter()" >Submit</button>';
      }
      //var filter = '<label for="years" style="font-size: 20px">Years</label><br><select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="filterYear" name="years" required><option value="" selected>Choose...</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2021">2021</option></select><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="FilterButton" onclick="filter()" >Submit</button>';
      document.getElementById("digitalgoods-030521182921-1").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("displayRecords").innerHTML = displayTable;
      document.getElementById("firstLastName").innerHTML = "USER: " + name;
      document.getElementById("myFilter").innerHTML = filter;
      document.getElementById("LoginButton").innerHTML = "Login";
      document.getElementById("username").value = '';
      document.getElementById("password").value = '';
    }
    </script>
```

```
  <div>
    <h2 id="firstLastName">

    </h2>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" id="currentUser" value=""/>
  <div id ="myFilter" class="form-group">

  </div>

  </div>
  <div id="displayRecords" style="padding: 10px;" >
    
  </div>
```

**Modifications done:**

- Include empty form-group class
- Include hidden input to hold current logged-in user
- Create a reusable function `displayTable()`
- Create an html content for the drop-down filter. See variable `filter`.
- Include another argument when calling `GetRecords(username, filter)`
- Create a new function `filter()`
- During initial log-in, filter will be set to "None". filter will be set depending on the option selected

---

**Code.gs (modifications)**

```
function GetRecords(username,filter) {
  var filteredDataRangeValues = GetUsernameAssociatedProperties(username);
  var resultArray = GetPaymentRecords(filteredDataRangeValues,filter);
  var resultFilter = getYears();

  result = {
    data: resultArray,
    filter: resultFilter
  };
  return result;
}

function getYears() { 
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var yearSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Configuration"); 
  var getLastRow = yearSheet.getLastRow();
  var return_array = [];
  for(var i = 2; i <= getLastRow; i++)
  {
      if(return_array.indexOf(yearSheet.getRange(i, 2).getDisplayValue()) === -1) {
        return_array.push(yearSheet.getRange(i, 2).getDisplayValue());
      }
  }
  return return_array;  
}

function GetPaymentRecords(userProperties,filter) {
  var transpose = m => m[0].map((_, i) => m.map(x => x[i]));
  var resultArray = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var displaySheet = ss.getSheetByName(streetSheetName);
  var addressValues = displaySheet.getRange("B:C").getValues();
  var paidMonthValues = displaySheet.getRange("G:AD").getValues();
  //Logger.log(addressValues);
  //Logger.log(transpose(paidMonthValues));
  userProperties.forEach((v, i) => {
    var userHouseNumber = v[1];
    var userStreet = v[2];
    var column = addressValues.reduce(function callbackFn(accumulator, currentValue, index, array) {
      if (currentValue[0] == userHouseNumber && currentValue[1] == userStreet) {
        return index
      } else {
        return accumulator
      }
    }, '');
    //Logger.log(column);
    Logger.log(filter)
    Logger.log(paidMonthValues);
    
    if(filter=="None"){
      var result = transpose(paidMonthValues).map(function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
        return [element[0], userHouseNumber, userStreet, element[column] || '']
      });
    }else{
      var result = transpose(paidMonthValues).map(function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
        if(element[0].includes(filter))return [element[0], userHouseNumber, userStreet, element[column] || '']
      });
    }
    
    resultArray = resultArray.concat(result);
    //Logger.log(resultArray);  
  })

  //Remove null elements
  resultArray = resultArray.filter(element=>{
    Logger.log(element!=null)
    return element != null;
  });
  return resultArray;
}
```

**Modifications done:**

- Modified `GetRecords()` and `GetPaymentRecords()` to include filter option
- Add removal of null elements in the `resultArray`. (Null elements may exist when filter option was used due to the map() used)

### Output:

**(After user logged-in)**

[image]

**(After user selects a filter)**

[image]

### (UPDATE):

The following modifications where done to create a drop-box based on the list of years available in the configuration sheet.

WebAppLogin.html

- displayTable() was modified that will accept an object as its parameter which contains an array data and an array of filter strings.
- displayTable() was modified to update the drop-down options based on the filter strings available

Code.gs

- getYears() was added that will read the sheet "Configuration" to get the filter string values
- GetRecords() was modified to return an object which contains an array of record data and an array of filter strings.

Comment: Based on my research it is quite complicated to save an array in an html input that is why i just modified your existing code to filter the array result in the code.gs rather than in the html

Comment: Hi @MATHAVAN A L KRISHNAN, I updated the answer that will read the drop-down values from the configuration sheet